Unexpected token in angular project
i'm newbie at angular and i'm doing my first steps on web design. I'm doing a personal project practicing about reactive forms. the project was running fine but today when i tried to run it with the ng serve -o comand i got the following error:
An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid or unexpected token
it gives me a log file to check and the log file is showing this:
[error] D:\Desarrollo\angular\reactiveForm-Practice\node_modules\semver\node_modules\yallist\yallist.js:1
$  m  mo L D  ; %g ?w  ŷ   ovH0  a 5  * ؒ  l͛ S iy r O7    %L]  %   hk
^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:128:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1332:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Desarrollo\angular\reactiveForm-Practice\node_modules\semver\node_modules\lru-cache\index.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)


How can ifix this issue, i would aprecciate any help, thanks.
I tried erasing the node - modules folder but not able to erase it, it seems to be undeleatable.

Compilation done for newer supported JS version than actually use.d

more info is needed ,cli version, and source code, can you post it i github or anoteer repository?

Hello David, yes the repository is https://github.com/Milioamperio299/reactiveForm-Practice.git
